# Texture Rendering works on Windows but not Mac OS?

Tags: java, libgdx

So I am building this game and a map editor / sdk type deal to go with it. On my desktop pc running w7 and my buddies laptop running w10 everything works absolutely fine. I can add objects and move them around (there is also an auto updating properties window to go with each obj) and everything is great.

I am currently traveling so I decided to copy the project over to my macbook. Everything UI wise still works with the exception of things stopped rendering. I know the objects exist within the app because I can click where they would be and the properties update like the would on my desktop the textures just simply are not rendering. I am using a standard orthographic camera and spritebatch setup i've done 1million times and i have all the matricies being forwarded to the batch from the camera as well as your standard color buffer bit glclear call and glclearcolor calls. Why would moving this project to my macbook make textures quit rendering?

Using jdk / jre 1.8_91 on both machines and the same ver of eclipse (mars).

EDIT: ShapeRenderer is not working as well. I also have already tried removing the camera entirely and still no-go. During my rendering loop I am able to print out accurate pixel RBG values and width/height of images that should be rendering which means I am not dealing with some odd nullptr or anything of that nature.

Comment: Are you sure the textures get loaded? This sounds like a filesystem / resource issue, e.g. slash (mac) vs. backslash (windows) in paths, case sensitive vs. case insensitive names etc.

Comment: Yes otherwise I wouldn't be able to get widths and heights of the textures post loading and no nullpointerexceptions got thrown so they are loaded just the rendering is messing up for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. By resizing my window the jmenus popup and so do all my renderables. For some reason calling pack() is not working on the frame and I have to resize it to refresh everything at first launch of the app now for this problem =P

Comment: Maybe the "packed" component has a different minimum size on mac?